# Finding the Probability of a multiple using geometric distribution

Tags: probability

Let X be a geometric distribution with parameter $$p = \frac 19$$

i.e. $$P(X = k) = \frac {\frac{8}{9}^{( k−1)}}{9} $$

for k ∈ {1, 2, 3, . . .}

Let A be the event that X is a multiple of four. What is the value of P(A)?

How do I find k in this instance?

Comment: You want the event which is the union over $k=4,8,12,16,20,\ldots$ which since they are disjoint has a probability which is the sum of the corresponding probabilities

Answer (score 1):

$$P(X\in A)=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}P(X=4k)$$
which gives you a geometric series to compute.